# Sort array in descending order & returning only matching elemnet from array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ff961d4404a0dccec4f71"),
    "tier" : "3",
    "agentName" : "Dial2Travel1",
    "meeting" : [ 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "call back after 4 days",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-02-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "wrong number",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "packages request",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ff961d4404a0dccec4f72"),
    "tier" : "3",
    "agentName" : "Dial2Travel2",
    "meeting" : [ 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "call back after 4 days",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-02-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "wrong number",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "packages request",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ff961d4404a0dccec4f73"),
    "tier" : "3",
    "agentName" : "Dial2Travel3-",
    "meeting" : [ 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "call back after 4 days",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-02-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "wrong number",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "packages request",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ff961d4404a0dccec4f74"),
    "tier" : "3",
    "agentName" : "Dial2Travel4",
    "meeting" : [ 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "call back after 4 days",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-02-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "wrong number",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "meetingDate" : ISODate("2019-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "comment" : "packages request",
            "meetingDoneBy" : {
                "$ref" : "salesExecutive",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5c6b9dc9d56dbad67a951786")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort the **meeting** array in descending order & then apply pagination to only retrieve matching meetings in the response & not the complete array.
So for the 1st page I want to request 5 meetings then only 5 meetings will be returned/projected. On 2nd page request next 5 & so on.
What currently I am getting is a complete array of meeting. This is not what I want.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB, Flask, aggregate with $unwind query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323316/mongodb-flask-aggregate-with-unwind-query)

Answer (score 0):

give this aggregation query a try:

```java
var pageNum = 1;
var resPerPage = 5;
var skipAmt = pageNum * resPerPage;

db.Test.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$meeting"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "meeting": "$meeting"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "meeting.meetingDate": - 1
        }
    },
    {
        $skip: skipAmt
    },
    {
        $limit: resPerPage
    }
]);
```